# Is there a way in Jackson to write HashMap in to a list of object and vice versa

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'd like to transform

```
 HashMap<String, Car> to JSON list of cars
```

when serializing  and from

```
 List<Car> (JSON) to HashMap<String, Car>
```

when deserializing.

I know I can write a custom serializer/deserializer but I was wondering if there was a easier/built in way in jackson to achieve this.

Comment: Instead of serializing the entire map, serialize only the collection of values you get by calling the `values()` method.

Comment: So are you saying create a sealiser and just do map.values() ?

Comment: That should provide you with a json list of cars.

Comment: The only problem with that approach is tthen EVERY map i create in my program will use that serializer so if i have Map<String, int> it would serialize using values()... so i guess what im saying it how can i only restrict Map<String,Car> to serialize

Comment: I think you need to provide some actual code. What you're saying doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your HashMap's key is also in your value object (like a VIN for a car), so you can easily re-build the key later, then maybe the annotations @JsonGetter/@JsonSetter can help:

Let's say you have something like a car rental station:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CarRentalStation {

    private String location = "Atlanta";
    private Map<String, Car> cars = new HashMap<String, Car> (){{
        put("A123", new Car("A123", "BMW 120d"));
        put("B321", new Car("B321", "Volkswagen Golf 2.0 TDI"));
    }};

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @JsonGetter("cars")
    public List<Car> getCarsAsList() {
        return cars.values().stream().collect(Collectors.<Car>toList());
    }

    @JsonSetter("cars")
    public void setCarsAsList(List<Car> cars) {
        Map<String, Car> deserializedCars = cars.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Car::getVin, car -> car));
        this.cars = deserializedCars;
    }

    //toString ...    
}
```

The car looks like that:

```
public class Car {

    private String vin;
    private String model;

    Car() {
    }

    public Car(String vin, String model) {
        this.vin = vin;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getVin() {
        return vin;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }   

    // toString ... 
}
```

You can easily serialize/ deserialize it:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String json = om.writeValueAsString(new CarRentalStation());
System.out.println(json);
// prints: {"location":"Atlanta","cars":[{"vin":"B321","model":"Volkswagen Golf 2.0 TDI"},{"vin":"A123","model":"BMW 120d"}]}

CarRentalStation deserializedCarRentalStation =  om.readValue(json, CarRentalStation.class);
System.out.println(deserializedCarRentalStation.toString());
// prints: CarRentalStation{location='Atlanta', cars={B321=Car{vin='B321', model='Volkswagen Golf 2.0 TDI'}, A123=Car{vin='A123', model='BMW 120d'}}}
```

Comment: this works from map to list but how about the other way around? Deserializing list<object> to map?

Comment: I think I just to create a setCars() method and take in Collection and transform into map